# What does PH stand for in PHAsset in Apple's documentation?

Tags: ios

Similar to how I can easily google NSURLSession, NS stand for NextStep, what does PH stand for in PHAsset? I know a lot of people assume PH stands for Photo but then, there are also libraries that start with PHPhotoLibrary which converts to PhotoPhotoLibrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhotoKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit. All classes in PhotoKit share those same initials.